# How to use Retrofit and Loader class in the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit, loader, android-databinding

I used Retrofit to receive the json from my RESTful, it is fine. And I tried to implement the Loader class to maker the data loading logic more clear instead of putting it in a onCreateView method to load it, which is not quite a clear logic for loading data. However, I found a bit confused if I tried to use AsyncTaskLoader( which one supposed to receive the data from asynchronous process) for my retrofit. And I stuck in this point. Retrofit is already an asynchronous process and I wonder should I used the asynchronous call or synchronous call in the retrofit inside the AsyncLoader class.

```
package generic.fragment;
import android.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import generic.adapter.BaseListAdapter;

public abstract class SwipedLoaderListFragment<Bean, Adapter extends BaseListAdapter<Bean, ? extends ViewDataBinding>> extends SwipedListFragment<Bean, Adapter> implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Bean>> {
    public SwipedLoaderListFragment(FragConfig pFragConfig) {
        super(pFragConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public List<Bean> loadData(String query) {
        List<Bean> list = new ArrayList<>();
        return list;
    }
    @Override
    public void refreshing() {
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this).forceLoad();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Bean>> loader, List<Bean> data) {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(data);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Bean>> loader) {
        mAdapter.clear();
    }
}
```

And this is the fragment I used.

```
public class LocListFragment extends SwipedLoaderListFragment<String, SimpleStringAdapter> {
    public LocListFragment() {
        super(new FragConfigBuilder(R.layout.swiped_list).setEnableSwipe(false).setFilterable(true).setEnableDivider(true).build());
    }
    @Override
    public void query(String query) {
        super.query(query);
        mAdapter.filter(query);
    }
    @Override
    public void queryWhenTextChanged(String query) {
        super.queryWhenTextChanged(query);
        mAdapter.filter(query);
    }
    @Override
    public SimpleStringAdapter initListAdapter() {
        return new SimpleStringAdapter(getActivity(), loadData("")) {
            @Override
            public ListItemStringBinding bind(ListItemStringBinding pBinding, String pS, int pPosition) {
                pBinding.setText(pS);
                return pBinding;
            }
        };
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent lIntent = new Intent();
        lIntent.putExtra(SCConstants.PARAM_LOC, mAdapter.getItem(position));
        getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, lIntent);
        getActivity().finish();
    }
    @Override
    public String getHintStr() {
        return "Input Location";
    }
    @Override
    public String getSearchTitle() {
        return "Location Search";
    }
    @Override
    public Loader<List<String>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new AsyncTaskLoader<List<String>>(getActivity()) {
            @Override
            public List<String> loadInBackground() {
                //here will be the retrofit call
                return null;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the Loader's `loadInBackground` method is already asynchronous, it would probably be easier to use a synchronous retrofit call (i.e., use `execute` rather than `enqueue`).

For your loader to work, you will also need to override `onStartLoading`.  An implementation might look something like this:

```
public class MyLoader<List<String>> extends AsyncTaskLoader {
    List<String> mResult;

    @Override
    public List<String> loadInBackground() {
         mResult = myHttpApi.execute()...
         return mResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
         if (mResult != null) {
             deliverResult(mResult);
         }
         if (mResult == null || takeContentChanged()) {
             forceLoad();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like when the data is needed to loaded inside the fragment when it is created, the customRetrofitAsyncTaskLoader should be implemented. And only synchronous call should be used. And for the outgoing retrofit call , they would be in asynchronous process.